# parsing an integer field in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, crystal-reports

I want to split every digit in an integer field in an sql table . example of that would be: 
financialNb = 7869
i need the 7 as first digit, 8 as second, 6 as third and 9 as fourth. this is needed because I want every digit to be used as 1 data field in a crystal report?

Comment: Is this field always 4 digits or does it change?

Answer (score 1):

First you have to convert or cast numbers into text before you can manipulate them in this way. The functions you are looking for are [CAST()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and [SUBSTRING()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187748.aspx). To get the numbers to start from the right, you can use [REVERSE()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180040.aspx).

Try this example:

```
SELECT 7869 AS field1
INTO #tmp

SELECT   SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CAST(field1 AS VARCHAR(255))),8,1) AS [Column8]
    ,SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CAST(field1 AS VARCHAR(255))),7,1) AS [Column7]
    ,SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CAST(field1 AS VARCHAR(255))),6,1) AS [Column6]
    ,SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CAST(field1 AS VARCHAR(255))),5,1) AS [Column5]
    ,SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CAST(field1 AS VARCHAR(255))),4,1) AS [Column4]
    ,SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CAST(field1 AS VARCHAR(255))),3,1) AS [Column3]
    ,SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CAST(field1 AS VARCHAR(255))),2,1) AS [Column2]
    ,SUBSTRING(REVERSE(CAST(field1 AS VARCHAR(255))),1,1) AS [Column1]
FROM #tmp

DROP TABLE #tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your question is about parsing `7869`.  Using the `substring` function for this:

```
select substring(cast(<col> as char(4)), 1, 1) as FirstChar,
       substring(cast(<col> as char(4)), 2, 1) as SecondChar,
       substring(cast(<col> as char(4)), 3, 1) as ThirdChar,
       substring(cast(<col> as char(4)), 4, 1) as FourthChar
from YourTable
```

I might be interpreting the ordering of the digits incorrectly, and this assumes the strings are always 4 digits and that you want characters.  An alternative way is just to look at this as numbers:

```
select <col%10 as FirstNum,
       (col/10) %10 as SecondNum,
       (col/100)%10 as ThirdNum,
       (col/1000)%10 as FourthNum
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulo operator (`%`) to get the digits of an integer, without using the slower string manipulation functions, like this

```
select 
  value % 100000000 / 10000000,
  value % 10000000 / 1000000,
  value % 1000000 / 100000,
  value % 100000 / 10000,
  value % 10000 / 1000,
  value % 1000 / 100,
  value % 100 / 10,
  value % 10
from testData
```

Here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/08a83/9) to play with.
If the field is always 4 numbers long, you can get away with:

```
select 
  value / 1000 as Thousands,
  value % 1000 / 100 as Hundreds,
  value % 100 / 10 as Tens,
  value % 10 as Units
from testData
```

If, however, you need to use it on arbitrary numbers, you could create a user-defined table valued function, that will return the digits in a table, like this:

```
create function dbo.getDigits(@Input int)
returns @Digits table
(
    Digit int,
    Position int
)
as begin
  declare @pos int
  declare @digit int
  set @pos = 0

  if @input = 0
  begin
    -- zero is just a single zero digit at position 1
    insert into @digits values (0,1)
    return
  end

  while @input<>0 begin
    set @pos=@pos+1
    set @digit = @input % 10
    set @input = @input / 10
    insert into @digits values (@digit, @pos)
  end
  return
end
```

and use it like this:

```
SELECT td.ID, td.Value, d.Digit, d.Position 
FROM   testData td
    CROSS APPLY dbo.getDigits(td.Value) AS d
order by td.ID, d.Position Desc
```

(Here's another [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/88ea0/8), based on the previous one)